# How to get all title elements from HTML? HTMLAgilityPack,C#

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Working about parser music site. Need to get more info about songs, in playlist.
After my slip with AngleSharp, I use HTMLAgilityPack.
So, title of the song located, for example:

```
        <div class="datagrid-cell cell-artist">
<div class="ellipsis"><a class="datagrid-label datagrid-label-main" itemprop="byArtist" title="Drake" href="/ru/artist/246791">Drake</a></div></div>
```

But with my code, I can't get the attribute I need.
Code (use the [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326502/how-to-get-href-elements-and-attributes-for-each-node)):

```
 class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.deezer.com/ru/playlist/2872124702");
        document.LoadHtml(html);
        if (document.DocumentNode != null)
        {

            foreach (HtmlNode node in document.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d =>
            d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("ellipsis")))
            {
                string title = node.SelectSingleNode(".//a").Attributes["title"].Value; //I think - need InnerText
                Console.WriteLine(title);
            }
```

Help,please, I have no more idea, how to do this. 
Good luck!

Comment: For example,website listed in string html

Comment: havent worked with it for a long time, but maybe: `foreach (var node in document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/link[@itemprop='byArtist']"))`

Comment: @Dementic nope(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion in the comment seems to work,
See working version here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/h8OrbG

```
    using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        var html = "<div class='datagrid-cell cell-artist'><div class='ellipsis'><a class='datagrid-label datagrid-label-main' itemprop='byArtist' title='Drake' href='/ru/artist/246791'>Drake</a></div></div>";
        doc.DocumentNode.AppendChild(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.CreateNode(html));
        foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@itemprop='byArtist']"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["title"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The application is in break mode.
Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code). System.NullReferenceException

Comment: You are in debug mode... am not sure what you want me to do with that...

Comment: Please open the link i attached and click run, you will see the results at the bottom.

Comment: Yep,It's work, but need to use  string title = node.InnerText; instead node.Attributes["title"].Value.